# ReactiveStreams NPE when using publishOn with custom Publisher

Tags: kotlin, reactive-streams

When I'm using Reactive Streams (https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core) with a custom `Publisher` in combination with the `publishOn` function, I always get an NPE. What is wrong with my code? Do I use the `Publisher` in a wrong way?

```
Flux.from(MyPublisher())
            .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
            .subscribe { println("<-- $it received") }

class MyPublisher : Publisher<Int> {
    override fun subscribe(sub: Subscriber<in Int>) {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(300)
            sub.onNext(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.onNext(FluxPublishOn.java:212)
    at org.guenhter.kotlin.hello.MyPublisher.subscribe(HelloWorld.kt:18)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSource.subscribe(FluxSource.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn.subscribe(FluxPublishOn.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6447)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:6614)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6440)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6404)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6347)
    at org.guenhter.kotlin.hello.HelloWorldKt.main(HelloWorld.kt:11)
```

Comment: Please please not just downvote, but leave a helpful comment why you think this question is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Publisher` is defined by the "reactive-streams" standard and has a number of requirements. One of these requirements is that `Subscriber.onSubscribe` HAS to be called before any of the other methods in order to follow the protocol.

Since you haven't done this, it means something probably is not initialized properly, causing the NPE inside of the reactor class.

However even if you fix this problem the standard is designed to be **reactive** which means it only emits data when the subscriber asks for it. Since you will be sending it data regardless that will probably cause an exception later down the line. Use `Flux.create` to create an emitter that can properly handle requests instead of creating your own Publisher implementation.